# How we can insert multiple paragraphs after the insertion of table in google docs using google docs api with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am working on google docs api.I want to create a google docs with google docs api using PHP.AS per my requirement I want some paragraphs then insert a table and then again a paragraph as shown in below picture-
[image]

I am able to  insert texts like this -

```
$requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
            'insertText' => [
                'text' => 'Paragraph 1',
                'location' => [
                    'index' => 1,
                ]
            ]
        ));
```

I am also able to add table like this-

```
$requests [] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
    'insertTable' => [
        'rows' =>  4,
        'columns' =>  4,
        'endOfSegmentLocation' => [
          'segmentId' => ''
        ],
    ],
]);
```

but after adding this table I want to add another paragraph as shown in pic.I have added another insertion text request after this table request like this -

```
$requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
            'insertText' => array(
                'text' => "Paragraph 2", 
                'endOfSegmentLocation' => array(
                    'segmentId' => '',
                    ),
            ),
        ));
```

But like this i want to add more paragraphs after the insertion of table and for that I need index location but I am not able to do that. Can anybody help me on this how to add contents like this as shown in above pic.It would be a great huge help if anyone can help me through this.I want this in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I thought that when the contents are inserted with the reverse order, `index` can be ignored. In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

```php
$documentId = "###"; // Please set the Google Document ID.

$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => 'Paragraph 1',
            'location' => [
                'index' => 1,
            ]
        ]
    )),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertTable' => [
            'rows' =>  4,
            'columns' =>  4,
            'location' => [
              'index' => 1
            ],
        ],
    ]),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => 'Paragraph 2',
            'location' => [
                'index' => 1,
            ]
        ]
    ))
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => array_reverse($requests)
));
$responses = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

#### Sample script 2:

Or, if you want to append the text of "Paragraph 2" after the text "Paragraph 1" and a table were inserted, you can append the text using the following script.

```php
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => "Paragraph 2", // or "\nParagraph 2"
            'endOfSegmentLocation' => [
                'segmentId' => ''
            ],
        ]
    )),
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => array_reverse($requests)
));
$responses = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

- By this request, `Paragraph 2` can be appended to the document body. Also, In this case, `index` for putting the text can be ignored.
- About `'text' => "Paragraph 2"`, when the paragraph is the same with the last paragraph, you can create new paragraph by `'text' => "\nParagraph 2"`.

#### Sample script 3:

If you want to insert the text by retrieving the index, you can also the following sample script.

```php
$documentId = "###"; // Please set the Google Document ID.

$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => 'Paragraph 1',
            'location' => [
                'index' => 1,
            ]
        ]
    )),
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request([
        'insertTable' => [
            'rows' =>  4,
            'columns' =>  4,
            'endOfSegmentLocation' => [
                'segmentId' => ''
            ],
        ],
    ]),
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => array_reverse($requests)
));
$responses = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);

$obj = $service->documents->get($documentId);
$content = $obj->getBody()->getContent();
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'insertText' => [
            'text' => 'Paragraph 2',
            'location' => [
                'index' => end($content)->getEndIndex() - 1,
            ]
        ]
    ))
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));
$responses = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest)

Comment: A very wise approach. Havent thought of adding the reverse order. Very ingenious.

Comment: @Octavia Sima Thank you for your comment. When the coordinate of content is changed when the content is inserted, this method is useful. This method can be used for Google Spreadsheet and so on. As additional information, recently, Google Docs API can append the content. So the method without using "reverse" can be also used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have PHP in me so I can only provide you the request and process on how to insert paragraphs after the table.

#### Sample Doc:

[image: sample]

After inserting your table, you need to `get` the document's last `endIndex` by using `get` request and pass `body/content/endIndex` as your field parameter values. This will return this response from using the above sample doc:

```
{
  "body": {
    "content": [
      {
        "endIndex": 1
      },
      {
        "endIndex": 576
      },
      {
        "endIndex": 614
      },
      {
        "endIndex": 615
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You have to iterate all the `endIndex` from the response and get the last one (e.g. `615`). Subtract `1` from the last `endIndex` value and then pass it as index location in the next insert paragraph response.

#### Sample request:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "location": {
          "index": 614
        },
        "text": "\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.\n"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I have enclosed the text with `\n` at both ends to have some space.
- You can also append all your paragraphs into one request so you wouldn't have to `get` the last `endIndex` everytime.
- You can also use **offsets** by counting every character you add so that you can follow what index you should use next.
- As for the paragraph formatting like having indention and aligning the paragraph to right, see [changing paragraph formatting](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/format-text#changing_paragraph_formatting) and see the sample request. If you have a question regarding this, I recommend you post a separate post for it.